# Converting Sub to Function

Tags: excel, vba

This sub macro fills from the current active cell to the right, `Numvendors` amount of times with the input function.

```
Sub FunctionFill()

    Dim myFunction As String: myFunction = "=SUM(A1:A5)"
    Dim Numvendors As Integer: Numvendors = 4
    Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, Application.ActiveCell.Column).Resize(, Numvendors).Formula = myFunction
    
End Sub
```

How do I change this sub into a function that takes `Numvendors` and `myFunction` as inputs and outputs the range.

Comment: `function FunctionAutoFill(numVendors as long, myFunction as string) as Excel.range`  i'd use a variable of range type to hold `Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, Application.ActiveCell.Column).Resize(, Numvendors)`, so `set myRangeVariable = ` here, and then you need to finish with `set FunctionAutoFill=myRangeVariable`

Comment: How would you use the `myFunction` variable here? Would appreciate an example.

Comment: How would `myFunction` be related to the new function? It has nothing to do with it and the new function should be created without it. But you may want something different which you failed to describe. Think about it for a while. What do you need this range reference (new function) for? The result of the function is the range `ActiveCell.Resize(, NumVendors)` (instead of `Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, Application.ActiveCell.Column).Resize(, Numvendors)`). You don't need a function for it.